# Bringing food into Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

I am travelling to Australia and Norfolk Island next week and I wondered if I can bring the following food:

- Weetbix
- Tea Bags
- Marmite

Comment: What research have you done? What don't you understand about the import rules?

Comment: Where will you be coming from? Do you really mean [Weet-Bix](https://www.weetbix.com.au/) (which is an Australian product), or [Weetabix](https://www.weetabix.co.uk/) (which is a UK product)? What kind of tea? Is it commercially packaged? Do you mean [Marmite](https://www.unilever.co.uk/brands/food-and-drink/marmite.html) (the UK product) or [Marmite](https://marmite.co.nz/) (the NZ product)?

Comment: I would also suggest that Weetbix, tea, and Vegemite (similar to Marmite but definitely not identical) are some of the most widely available products in Australian food stores. Even on Norfolk Island.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please clarify this question answering @GregHewgill's questions since right now it is kinda vague.

Comment: bringing food products into Australia is not advised, bringing food products already available easily within Australia is going to raise serious red flags about what you're trying to smuggle in those containers.